# Mimic System.Drawing.Drawing2D.Matrix .net class in javascript

Tags: .net, html5-canvas, system.drawing

I'm rebuilding a .net drawing application in javascript, using HTML5 canvas for the drawing. To make it easy for myself I also rebuild some System.Drawing classes in javascript, one of them is the Matrix class. The .net Matrix class has a constructor which let's you map a rectangle to a parallelogram, see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ka4k5fxa#Y0
But I can not find out which calculation I have to do, to get this also working in Javascript,
any Matrix experts here, to help me out?

thanks,

Rob

Answer (score 1):

Well I found it, by looking at the source of the wine library: http://source.winehq.org/source/dlls/gdiplus/matrix.c

Comment: Or you can use ILSpy to get the (decompiled) source code of any .NET class.

Comment: No, that won't work because the Matrix calculation is done in the native win32 Gdi+ dll and not in the Matrix .NET class.

Comment: Really? Sounds silly to incur the cost of interop marshaling just to do a simple calculation...

Comment: Yes, really, this is the Gdiplus.dll function which does the calculation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms535323(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Oh I believed you, I was just surprised.